# Can you run Twitter Storm on YARN

Tags: apache-storm, cascading, hadoop-yarn

Can Twitter Storm be managed and run as a YARN application? Further, is it sensible to do this? I'm hoping to build a YARN-based library that manages batch and streaming processes within the metaphor of pipes. E.g. faucets (sources), pipes (connectors and filters), tanks (batch processes), and drains (sinks to FS, database, etc.).

Comment: Take a look at [storm-yarn](https://github.com/yahoo/storm-yarn) and the related [article](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/storm-yarn-released-open-source-143745133.html)

Answer (score 2):

It seems pretty experimental but you can look at Storm-Yarn convergence project

http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/storm-yarn-released-open-source-143745133.html